# Custom error messages in rspec when comparing equality

Tags: rspec

Is it possible to add a custom error message to an expectation that looks like this:

```
expect(user.uid).to eq uid
```

I tried:

```
expect(user.uid).to eq uid, "Custom message"
```

because of https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/customized-message but I guess that's an operator matcher. Is there another way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turned out, what I was doing was mostly ok:

```
expect(user.uid).to eq(uid), "Custom message"
```

works, it's just that I was getting a failure with `user` being nil, and the call crashing instead of generating a matching error.

Answer (score -1):

As you said, customized failure messages are not supported for matchers based on Ruby's built-in operators for strings, numbers and arrays (`==`, `>`, `<=`, `=~`, etc.).

The purpose of customized messages is to help debugging complex expectations on custom objects, where even with good structure and descriptions of contexts and examples, the default failure message may not give a clear indication on what exactly went wrong.

In the case of operator matchers, default messages are always as clear and explicit as they can possibly be. So I believe that disallowing their customization was a conscious design decision.

Comment: Every time I get an error, I have to go in and add a tiny bit of print code to inspect a structure to understand what went wrong, so that I can fix the test. That's really annoying.

Comment: @MartaSilva Do you mind sharing an example of your expectation and the failure message that you receive?